# UISegmentedControl null index

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have been creating my application in a primarily programatic approach and have been attempting to add a UISegmentedControl to the UINavigationControl Toolbar. I have the view created and shown and an action for when the UISegmentedControl is selected. The issue is that at any point I call selectedSegmentIndex, it returns a null value. Any ideas why?

```
    NSArray *segmentArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Factory Laods", @"User Loads", nil];

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems: segmentArray];

segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    UIBarButtonItem *segmentedButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:flexibleSpace, segmentedButton, flexibleSpace, nil];
[self setToolbarItems:array];
```

-------- action method ------------

```
- (void) action:(id)sender {

UISegmentedControl *segment = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
NSLog(@"Button %@", [segment selectedSegmentIndex]);
```

}

The flexibleSpace object is a UIBarButtonItem initialized to be just a flexible space to center out the UISegmentedControl. After this item is added I can add an NSLog statement and identify a null value for the selectedSegmentIndex and it's also null when the event is triggered and checked in the action method. Thanks!

Comment: How did you implement the action method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action method might be helpful to see but in your code above, you've included `segmentedButton` to the array which you set the toolbar items with but you created it as `segmentedControl`.

Could be a typo, or your issue!

Comment: This is the code I used to create a bar button item to add to the toolbar, hence the segmentedButton being added. do I not need to do this?

     `UIBarButtonItem *segmentedButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:flexibleSpace, segmentedControl, flexibleSpace, nil];
    [self setToolbarItems:array];
    [delegate.navController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];`

Comment: I added more the rest of the code in my original question. but i don't know what I'm doing wrong still to get the null value returned.

Comment: Ah right, that explains that then. The problem looks to be what Jeremy alluded to in his answer. `selectedSegmentIndex` returns an `int`. If you modify the NSLog statement in your action method to `NSLog(@"Button %d", [segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex]);` what happens?

Comment: HA! something so simple right? Thanks guys... I should have known better. Guess I just need a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

`selectedSegmentIndex` returns an `NSInteger`, not an object. A `NULL` index is the index `0`, i.e., the first segment is currently selected.

Also, this line leaks the item array:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]
        initWithItems:
                [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Item 1", @"Item 2", nil]];
```

An owning reference is returned by `-initWithObjects:` and no corresponding `release` follows. You can either use `-arrayWithObjects:` or assign the returned array to a temporary variable so you can release it after initializing your segmented control.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I knew I was leaking, just haven't gotten to fixing it yet :P